# what table in mediawiki Database hold the page content

Tags: mediawiki

What table in the mediawiki database holds the page content?  I want to access the mediawiki's database directly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can take a look at the [database layout](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Database_layout) of MediaWiki. The page content is located in the table [`text`](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Text_table) (on PostgreSQL it seems to be `pagecontent`)

Comment: thanks @halfdan , do you know why is the name of the field is old_text, is that mean it isn't the current text?

Comment: From the documentation `Field names are a holdover from the 'old' revisions table in MediaWiki 1.4 and earlier.`

Answer (score 5):

I recently had a mediawiki installation go so wrong I needed to retrieve page content directly from the database. Below is the MYSQL statement I was able to use to retrieve the page content with.

```
SELECT  `old_text` 
FROM  `mw_text` 
WHERE  `old_id` 
IN (

    SELECT  `rev_text_id` 
    FROM  `mw_revision` 
    LEFT JOIN  `mw_page` ON  `page_latest` =  `rev_id` 
    WHERE  `page_title` LIKE (
         '%title_of_the_page%'
    )
)
```

Note: my table prefix is mw_ yours will probably be different

Answer (score 0):

Used this relationship to recover pages:
  page.page_latest=revision.rev_id -> revision.rev_text_id=text.old_id -> text.old_text
Ref: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Page_table

Comment: Please explain how this answers the question in some more detail.  How it answers the question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

I recently wanted to find articles containing URL, that the MediaWiki search
engine could not find for some reason. In MediaWiki 1.35 the `rev_text_id`
column has been deleted, so [willcwf's
answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28726862/9327802) did not work for me.

Basing on information from the MediaWiki documentation, I was able to create a
SQL query that works with newer MediaWiki versions:

```sql
SELECT
    (CASE
        WHEN p.page_namespace = 0 THEN '(Main)'
        WHEN p.page_namespace = 2 THEN 'User'
        WHEN p.page_namespace = 4 THEN 'Project'
        WHEN p.page_namespace = 6 THEN 'File'
        WHEN p.page_namespace = 8 THEN 'MediaWiki'
        WHEN p.page_namespace = 10 THEN 'Template'
        WHEN p.page_namespace = 12 THEN 'Help'
        WHEN p.page_namespace = 14 THEN 'Category'
        ELSE p.page_namespace
    END) as Namespace,
    p.page_title AS Title,
    t.old_text AS 'Text'
FROM
    page p
JOIN slots s ON
    s.slot_revision_id = p.page_latest
JOIN content c ON
    c.content_id = s.slot_content_id
JOIN `text` t ON
    t.old_id = REPLACE(c.content_address, 'tt:', '')
WHERE t.old_text LIKE '%needle%';
```